# React Native: Keyboard dismiss when changing focus in ScrollView

Tags: ios, react-native

In my React Native 0.22 iOS app, I have a `ScrollView` with multiple `TextInput` element in it.

I noticed that when I change focus from one TextInput to another by **tapping on the next TextInput**, the keyboard will dismiss and the next `TextInput` won't get focused immediately. It only get focus on the second time I tap on it (and then keyboard comes back again, really bad experience).

This behavior only happen on `TextInput` in `ScrollView`, but not `View`. I am wondering if there's any way to work around it?

Thank you!

Comment: Add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` to ScrollView.

Comment: this should be the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45901790/3507122

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just provide `keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"` prop to your scrollview.

From the docs -

> - 'never' (the default), tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When this happens, children won't receive the tap.
> - 'always', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically, and the scroll view will not catch taps, but children of the scroll view can catch taps.
> - 'handled', the keyboard will not dismiss automatically when the tap was handled by a children, (or captured by an ancestor).
>     false, deprecated, use 'never' instead
>     true, deprecated, use 'always' instead

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps

Answer (score 13):

`keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` deprecated

> `false`, deprecated, use `'never'` instead
>
> `true`, deprecated, use `'always'` instead

Answer (score 6):

Just add the following to your scrollview:

```
keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
```

This makes the scrollview to hide the keyboard if no editable control is focused.

Answer (score 4):

**RN 40+**

[ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

**keyboardShouldPersistTaps** :

> Determines when the keyboard should stay visible after a tap.

**keyboardDismissMode**

> Determines whether the keyboard gets dismissed in response to a drag

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true} keyboardDismissMode="on-drag">
    <TextInput>
</ScrollView>
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8234