# React Native Why does my keyboard dismiss instantly every time I tap on the textInput?

Tags: react-native, textinput, dismiss

My keyboard always dismisses instantly when I tap on the textInput. This only happens on Android.

It's strange that I've tried removing all irrelevant codes to textInput only, but the problem still exists. This only happens to one page of my app.

```
  <View>
            <TextInput
              style={{
                paddingVertical: 0,
                textAlignVertical: 'center',
                height: height * 0.05,
                width: width * 0.4,
                fontSize: height * 0.027,
                color: '#E1E1F2',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderBottomColor: '#6B778A',
                justifyContent: 'center',
              }}
              placeholderTextColor={'#6B778A'}
              underlineColorAndroid='black'/>
  </View>
```

I think there is nothing wrong with the codes, I really need help.

[screen record: media.giphy.com/media/Vc6AbKbMsnZX8ykKqR/giphy.gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNFrS.gif)

Comment: can you please provide all your code

Comment: Can you please provide the entire code, perhaps the entire render function? I believe there is a lot more than what you're showing here.

Comment: please add **onChangeText** event and  **value** in your textinput.

Comment: @Nagesh It doesn't work, I've tried it.

Comment: @swonder that's all the code. Here is the screen record media.giphy.com/media/Vc6AbKbMsnZX8ykKqR/giphy.gif

Comment: @pang please update your **latest** code with **onChangeText** event

Comment: @pang Please provide **all** code. There is something more than just a view and an input. That's for sure. Let us help you, post your code.

Comment: @Nagesh I did, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @swonder It's true, that's all the elements in the script.

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

it happens due to the react native screens , navigation stack and native dependency versions , just update them to the latest versions

Answer (score 1):

Probably your input is inside a ScrollView.

See [React Native: Keyboard dismiss when changing focus in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545145/react-native-keyboard-dismiss-when-changing-focus-in-scrollview) for solution.

Comment: It's only wrapped by a View.